# Unqlite python how to search collection for value that matches requirement

Tags: python, nosql, unqlite

We are to search collection and find businesses in the county from countyToSearch.
Save the name, full address, county and state to saveLocation1

How it is currently is not correct. I dont really understand the filter()

```
def FindBusinessBasedOnCounty(countyToSearch, saveLocation1, collection):

    c = collection.filter(lambda user: user['county'] == countyToSearch)
  
    f = open(saveLocation1, 'w')
    for bus in c:
       f.write(bus["Name"] + "$" + bus["FullAddress"] + "$" + bus["County"] + "$" + bus["State"] + "\n")
       f.close()
```

edit: I want the result to be the rows in database, where the countyname is equal to countyToSearch.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want the results to be and what you end up getting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you collection example, but what I see is :

1. filter should be used as:

   ```
   c = filter(lambda user: user['county'] == countyToSearch, collection)
   ```
2. you have uppercase `County` and lower case `county`.
3. In addition, you have to use `with open(..)` and not `open() ... close()`

Comment: I don't think that's it. Am I using that filter function correctly?

Comment: filter is used as filter(fun, collection), so probably not. You should share the error you are getting for better help